# Fill pdf form using itext in java having problems

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-form

I am using iText to fill pdf form, no error in console, but when i am opening the output pdf it is giving "Expected a dict object" and after it gives another message saying "This document enabled extended features in Adobe reader. The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available."

Also the output pdf have the changes i made but it does not have features of original pdf document, as the above message shows.

I have used below code...

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\asfs\\Downloads\\1013-Form22.pdf");
String name = "C:\\Users\\asfs\\Downloads\\Temp.pdf";

PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(name));
AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();

String last = "Form22_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Country_C[0]";

form.setField(last, "Sample Country name");

HashMap map = new HashMap();
map = form.getFields();
Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
    System.out.println("Field is >>>"+iterator.next());
// close pdf stamper
stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
stamp.close();
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
// open the pdf stamper in edit mode
stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(name), '\0', true);
```

The PdfStamper needs to be in append mode.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Now the "Expected a dict object" message is not coming, but the main problem still exists, which is the extended features of old pdf document. The new document is like a plain pdf document, it does not contain any form field and button.

Comment: How is the original pdf form/file created?

Comment: I updated the answer, you probably also need to open the pdfstamper in edit mode. More info at this link: http://support.itextpdf.com/node/6

Comment: The creation of pdf file not known to me. If it is using Adobe LifeCycle or Reader. Is there any change in filling forms in either cases ?

Comment: I can recommend the book, section section 8.7.1 does explain what is going on here. Did you try the append mode?

Comment: It is throwing exception...java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.java:1854)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setFullCompression(PdfWriter.java:2250)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.<init>(PdfStamperImp.java:128)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.<init>(PdfStamper.java:120)
 at com.faberwork.testmvc.ui.service.PdfFiller.main(PdfFiller.java:43)

Comment: Can you paste the line that throws the exception?

Comment: This line throws the exception...PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(name),'\0', true);

Comment: I am not sure why this exception is thrown. You can try to replace the '\0' with PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4. Or contact me on Skype so we can discuss in detail

Comment: I tried it too but same problem...It will be more helpfull if you can available on gmail. Thanks.

Comment: jasper - at - duizendstra.com. Send me the source and I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

if you want a Java code, here's a snippet I got from one a blog. But it uses pdf Nitro, in case this helps or let me know

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream editPdfDocument() throws Exception {
PdfReader reader = null;
PdfStamper stamper = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HashMap fieldsWithValues = new HashMap();
int user_id = 1234; // unique key for the object
String dirPath = “D:/abc”;// directory path
String fileName = “def.pdf”;// name of the file
try {
reader = new PdfReader(dirPath + “/” + fileName);
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baosPDF);
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
HashMap fields = form.getFields();
Set keys = fields.keySet();   // keys represents the names of all the form fields
fieldsWithValues = fetchFieldValuesForObject(user_id, keys);
// fetchFieldValuesForObject(user_id, keys) method will fetch the values of the fields from Database for object identified by user_id
Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
String fieldName = (String) itr.next();
String fieldValue = fieldsWithValues.get(fieldName) != null ? (String)(fieldsWithValues.get(fieldName)) : “”;
form.setField(fieldName, fieldValue);
}
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
} catch (Exception dex) {
if (stamper != null)
stamper.close();
if (reader != null)
reader.close();
throw dex;
}
return baosPDF;
}`enter code here`
```

It's Pdf form filling using Java that directly retrieves data from database, hope it works
[Visit Java Codes for Automatic form fill](http://www.trigent.com/blog/2013/08/14/java-application-development-automatic-form-filling-in-pdf-using-java-codes/)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, the stamp.setFormFlattening(true); you are calling, remove fields and replace that with content, that's why your new document doesn't preserve fields

Comment: This actually solved my problem. I was filling in fields but they weren't showing up in the modified text until I explicitly opened the form field. Don't know why I didn't see this anywhere... thanks very much :P